# Discord JS: bot reply via message button

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently learning how to use Discords Buttons but I ran into a problem.
The following code should create a button with the command /startgame, when you press this button it should just say "hello".

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageButton, MessageActionRow } = require("discord.js")

module.exports ={
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("startgame")
    .setDescription("Startet das Spiel"),
    async execute(interactionCreate) {
        if (interactionCreate.isCommand()) {
            const row1 = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId("start")
                        .setLabel("   Start   ")
                        .setStyle(3)
                        .setDisabled(false),
            )
            await interactionCreate.reply({content: " ", components: [row1]})
        }
        
        else if(interactionCreate.isButton()) {
            switch (interactionCreate.customId) {
                case "start": {
                    return interactionCreate.reply("hello")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It creates the button, but when you press it, it only says: `This interaction failed` I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

OK so one of these parts should be under your event listener `interactionCreate` rather than in a command. So if you have that section in your main bot.js file it would look like this:

Command File

```js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder
} = require("@discordjs/builders")
const {
    MessageButton,
    MessageActionRow
} = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("startgame")
        .setDescription("Startet das Spiel"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const row1 = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId("start")
                .setLabel("   Start   ")
                .setStyle(3)
            )
        return interaction.reply({
            components: [row1]
        })
    }
}
```

bot.js file - could be named whatever you named it

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        const buttonID = interaction.customId
        if (buttonID === 'start') {
            interaction.reply({
                content: 'Hello'
            })
        }
    }
})
```